# Cygwin django runserver - segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: django, segmentation-fault, cygwin

I am running the Django test server from a virtualenv - necessary to use supervisord to run Celery as a background process. When I try: "python manage.py runserver" from the cygwin shell I get the message "segmentation fault (core dumped). The supervisord process starts and I can't find any helpful messages in my error logs. Any suggestions for what may be the cause? Everything was working the last time I ran it (a common problem). I am running on Windows 7, using Python 2.7, and Django 1.6.5.

Is there a way to create a core dump in cygwin for something like this? I have looked around and seen suggestions of using userdump.exe or winDbg, but I haven't used either and they both seem to be for .exe files and I'm running a python script.

**UPDATE:**
A file named "python2.7.exe.stackdump" is created with the following contents:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=00180169A0D
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=00000003F336662F rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=00000001801C805F rdi=00000003F3366615
r8 =0000000000225418 r9 =8080808080808080 r10=FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFF
r11=00000003F3354522 r12=0000000000225420 r13=00000000FFFFFFFF
r14=0000000000225410 r15=0000000000000000
rbp=000000000000002B rsp=0000000000225318
program=C:\cygwin64\bin\python2.7.exe, pid 8872, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
```